# Basic limit question to understand the methods

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have a very basic question about proving limits with the epsilon-delta method.

So i want to prove  $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1-2x}\right)\:=\:1$ . first, i write it like that:
 $\left|\frac{1}{1-2x}\:-\:1\right|\:$ = $\left|\frac{2x}{1-2x}\right|\:$  = $\frac{2\left|x\right|}{\left|1-2x\right|}\:$ and from here i stuck. I know that i need to get |x|< *some expression of epsilon and stuff* that will be actually my delta. What i need to do from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show that $\dfrac{2}{|1-2x|}|x|$ can be made small (less than a preassigned $\epsilon$) by taking $|x|$ suitably close to $0$.

We can control $|x|$. The issue is with the term $\frac{2}{|1-2x|}$, which could potentially spoil things: We must make sure that $1-2x$ stays well away from $0$.

If we first of all specify that $\delta\lt \frac{1}{4}$, that forces $\frac{1}{2}\lt 1-2x$, which makes $\frac{2}{|1-2x|}\lt 4$.

Now it is easy to specify a $\delta$ that will work. We make $\delta=\min(\frac{1}{4},\frac{\epsilon}{4})$.

Comment: why δ<1/4 forces 1/2 < 1-2x?

Comment: If $|x|\lt \frac{1}{4}$, then in particular $x\lt \frac{1}{4}$, so $2x\lt \frac{1}{2}$, and therefore $1-2x\gt 1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. There is nothing special about choosing $\delta\lt \frac{1}{4}$. We can choose it $\lt \frac{1}{10}$, and then $1-2x\gt \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: and what is the secret to find that 1/4?

Comment: As I mentioned, anything "small" will do, the only thing we care about is forcing $1-2x$ away from $0$. The $\frac{1}{4}$ was basically chosen to make the arithmetic simple, but as mentioned above, I could have used $\frac{1}{10}$. Anything  substantially smaller than  $\frac{1}{2}$, which makes $1-2x$ equal to $0$, bad stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, then when $|x|<\max{\frac{\varepsilon}{4},\frac{1}{4}}$ you have:

$$\frac{2|x|}{|1-2x|}<\frac{2|x|}{\frac{1}{2}}=4|x|$$

It's because $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$, so $|1-2x|>\frac{1}{2}$, and finally:

$$4|x|<\varepsilon$$

Because $|x|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$.